# Does Matthew 4:8 indicate that the writers of the word of God were of the persuasion that the earth was flat?

Tags: matthew

An interesting point is that scripture claims that Shaitan took Yeshua to a high place so he could see the whole planet.
And that no matter how high you get, you can only see the whole planet if it is flat because the other side of the globe is always hidden.

Does this indicate that the writers of the word of God were of the persuasion that the earth was flat?

Matthew 4:8 KJV

> Again, the devil taketh him up into an exceeding high mountain, and sheweth him all the kingdoms of the world, and the glory of them;

Comment: The simplest explanation is that he was taken up in vision, like Ezekiel ch8, and he was not supposed to be seeing the world with his physical eyes, so the shape of the world would not be relevant.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: This verse is no more evidence of a flat earth than modern idiom talking of the "four corners of the world" suggesting it is square!

Comment: If the high mountain was the moon then it would take a whole day for Jesus to see all the kingdoms of the earth from the same viewpoint. Maybe they were not in a hurry. :)

Answer (score 0):

Matthew 4

> The devil took him up to a very high mountain, and showed him all the
> kingdoms of the world in their magnificence, 9 and he said to him,
> “All these I shall give to you, if you will prostrate yourself and
> worship me.

This might indicate a flat-earth concept on the part of the author only if the temptation is understood to be a physical vision. But two of these temptations should be understood as taking place in the spiritual world. First Jesus is transported to the Temple and then to a high mountain. But all the while, he has not physically left the desert. The author does not describe a physical journey, for Satan does not have the power to magically transport people over large distances. It is a spiritual experience that is envisioned.

Also notice that it is the "kingdoms of the world and their magnificence" and not "the whole world" that is mentioned. The devil tempts Jesus with a vision of magnificence and implied royal power rather than showing him the entire world, including deserts and oceans. No actual mountain is high enough to provide such vantage point in any case. Again, a spiritual vision is described and not a long-distance viewing of the entire Earth.

**Conclusion**: the author/s almost certainly had no idea of the Earth as a planet orbiting the Sun. So they they probably did think of the world as flat (or and least not as a globe). But they do not indicate this attitude in their description of Jesus' third temptation, as this was a spiritual vision of the earth's magnificent kingdoms, rather than looking at the entire physical world from a physical mountain.

Comment: FWIW, there's good documentation that at least the ancient Greeks were certainly aware that the world is round (see: https://www.keeptalkinggreece.com/2019/02/22/eratosthenes-earth-round-flat/ among several other places) and I believe that would have been pretty common knowledge. 

This tendency to think of our forebears as benighted and ignorant is certainly arrogant on our part.

Comment: I tried to distinguish between thinking the earth is flat and thinking of it as a planet or even a sphere, which is how the OP frames the question except in the headline.  Most sailors knew the horizon was curved but a curved horizon can lead to a curved drop off. Is there evidence that Eratosthenes' proof was widely accepted?

Comment: Fair point about it being thought of as a "planet". I don't know about "widely accepted" and I think the better question would be is there proof that the likely authors of the New Testament were aware of the fact.  There is evidence that back to 500 BCE the Greeks had the idea of a spherical earth: https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/200606/history.cfm but that doesn't prove the idea was widely accepted. On the other hand I think accepting that most ancient people thought the earth flat is also a premise that requires some proof.  Maybe you can supply some?

Answer (score 0):

I’m of the opinion that John was the first gospel written, then it was improved by Mark, then Matthew, then Luke. So it is no surprise that John knows nothing of the temptation in the wilderness. Mark, just has this:

> [Mar 1:12-13 NIV] [12] At once the Spirit sent him out into the wilderness, [13] and he was in the wilderness forty days, being tempted by Satan. He was with the wild animals, and angels attended him.

Notice that instead of fasting, angels met his needs. This is an allusion and enhancement of Elijah’s experience where crows brought him food twice per day:

> [1Ki 17:2-6 NIV] [1](https://youtu.be/pYdcQe-F_QA) Then the word of the LORD came to Elijah: [2](https://youtu.be/yr8BbsddlK8) "Leave here, turn eastward and hide in the Kerith Ravine, east of the Jordan. [3](https://youtu.be/GFK4wT9udFo) You will drink from the brook, and I have directed the ravens to supply you with food there." [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiwRI.png) So he did what the LORD had told him. He went to the Kerith Ravine, east of the Jordan, and stayed there. [6](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinnacle%20architecture&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi2vJ7TxZSDAxVIjYkEHawyCCcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pinnacle%20archi&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDoNCAAQgAQQigUQQxCxAzoICAAQgAQQsQM6CggAEIAEEIoFEENQ9jxY1WxgpowBaANwAHgAgAGmAYgB7wWSAQM5LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=w-Z9ZfbOCsiaptQPrOWguAI&bih=998&biw=2065) The ravens brought him bread and meat in the morning and bread and meat in the evening, and he drank from the brook.

Crows are extremely intelligent birds [and often give gifts to people they love to express their respect and appreciation](https://youtu.be/rS57A_2yWg4). In the story of Elijah, their gifts were miraculously appropriate:

> [1 Kings 17:4-6 NASB20] (4) "And it shall be that you will drink from the brook, and I have commanded the ravens to provide food for you there." (5) So he went and did [everything] according to the word of the LORD, for he went and lived by the brook Cherith, which is east of the Jordan. (6) And the ravens brought him bread and meat in the morning and bread and meat in the evening, and he would drink from the brook.

Science tells us that crows are as intelligent as a human seven year old! Here’s one [guiding a hedgehog cross a road to safety](https://youtu.be/yr8BbsddlK8), and another one of [a crow feeding a rodent!](https://youtu.be/pYdcQe-F_QA) Interestingly, Geese also watch out for others, [such as this hedgehog](https://youtu.be/GFK4wT9udFo).

So we should probably see in the incident with Elijah an allusion to the LORD’s provision for the Jews in their wanderings toward the Promised Land.

> [Exodus 16:3-15 NASB20] (3) The sons of Israel said to them, "If only we had died by the LORD'S hand in the land of Egypt, when we sat by the pots of meat, when we ate bread until [we were] full; for you have brought us out into this wilderness to kill this entire assembly with hunger!" (4) Then the LORD said to Moses, "Behold, I will rain bread from heaven for you; and the people shall go out and gather a day's portion every day, so that I may test them, whether or not they will walk in My instruction. (5) "On the sixth day, when they prepare what they bring in, it will be twice as much as they gather daily." (6) So Moses and Aaron said to all the sons of Israel, "At evening you will know that the LORD has brought you out of the land of Egypt; (7) and in the morning you will see the glory of the LORD, for He hears your grumblings against the LORD; and what are we, that you grumble against us?" (8) And Moses said, "[This will happen] when the LORD gives you meat to eat in the evening, and bread to the full in the morning; for the LORD hears your grumblings which you grumble against Him. And what are we? Your grumblings are not against us but against the LORD." (9) Then Moses said to Aaron, "Say to all the congregation of the sons of Israel, 'Come forward before the LORD, for He has heard your grumblings.'" (10) And it came about, as Aaron spoke to the entire congregation of the sons of Israel, that they looked toward the wilderness, and behold, the glory of the LORD appeared in the cloud. (11) And the LORD spoke to Moses, saying, (12) "I have heard the grumblings of the sons of Israel; speak to them, saying, 'At twilight you shall eat meat, and in the morning you shall be filled with bread; and you shall know that I am the LORD your God.'" (13) So it came about at evening that the quails came up and covered the camp, and in the morning there was a layer of dew around the camp. (14) When the layer of dew evaporated, behold, on the surface of the wilderness there was a fine flake-like thing, fine as the frost on the ground. (15) When the sons of Israel saw [it,] they said to one another, "What is it?" For they did not know what it was. And Moses said to them, "It is the bread which the LORD has given you to eat.

And with that, we should see that Jesus is the Bread of Life, provided from Heaven:

> [John 6:48-51 NASB20] (48) "I am the bread of life. (49) "Your fathers ate the manna in the wilderness, and they died. (50) "This is the bread that comes down out of heaven, so that anyone may eat from it and not die. (51) "I am the living bread that came down out of heaven; if anyone eats from this bread, he will live forever; and the bread which I will give for the life of the world also is My flesh."

So John has never heard this story and Mark knows of no challenges being posed to Jesus. He doesn’t fast but is fed **by angels**. Matthew has him fasting the whole time and adds the questions:

> [Mat 4:1-11 NIV] [1](https://youtu.be/pYdcQe-F_QA) Then Jesus was led by the Spirit into the wilderness to be tempted by the devil. [1](https://youtu.be/pYdcQe-F_QA) After fasting forty days and forty nights, he was hungry. [2](https://youtu.be/yr8BbsddlK8) The tempter came to him and said, "If you are the Son of God, tell these stones to become bread." [3](https://youtu.be/GFK4wT9udFo) Jesus answered, "It is written: 'Man shall not live on bread alone, but on every word that comes from the mouth of God.'" **[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiwRI.png) Then the devil took him to the holy city and had him stand on the highest point of the temple. [6](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinnacle%20architecture&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi2vJ7TxZSDAxVIjYkEHawyCCcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pinnacle%20archi&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDoNCAAQgAQQigUQQxCxAzoICAAQgAQQsQM6CggAEIAEEIoFEENQ9jxY1WxgpowBaANwAHgAgAGmAYgB7wWSAQM5LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=w-Z9ZfbOCsiaptQPrOWguAI&bih=998&biw=2065) "If you are the Son of God," he said, "throw yourself down. For it is written: " 'He will command his angels concerning you, and they will lift you up in their hands, so that you will not strike your foot against a stone.'" [7] Jesus answered him, "It is also written: 'Do not put the Lord your God to the test.'" [8] Again, the devil took him to a very high mountain and showed him all the kingdoms of the world and their splendor. [9] "All this I will give you," he said, "if you will bow down and worship me." [10] Jesus said to him, "Away from me, Satan! For it is written: 'Worship the Lord your God, and serve him only.'" [11] Then the devil left him, and angels came and attended him.**

Luke copies Matthew, omitting the ministering angels:

> [Luke 4:1-13 NIV] [1](https://youtu.be/pYdcQe-F_QA) Jesus, full of the Holy Spirit, left the Jordan and was led by the Spirit into the wilderness, **[1](https://youtu.be/pYdcQe-F_QA) where for forty days he was tempted by the devil. He ate nothing during those days, and at the end of them he was hungry.** [2](https://youtu.be/yr8BbsddlK8) The devil said to him, "If you are the Son of God, tell this stone to become bread." [3](https://youtu.be/GFK4wT9udFo) Jesus answered, "It is written: 'Man shall not live on bread alone.'" [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiwRI.png) The devil led him up to a high place and showed him in an instant all the kingdoms of the world. [6](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinnacle%20architecture&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi2vJ7TxZSDAxVIjYkEHawyCCcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pinnacle%20archi&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDoNCAAQgAQQigUQQxCxAzoICAAQgAQQsQM6CggAEIAEEIoFEENQ9jxY1WxgpowBaANwAHgAgAGmAYgB7wWSAQM5LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=w-Z9ZfbOCsiaptQPrOWguAI&bih=998&biw=2065) And he said to him, "I will give you all their authority and splendor; it has been given to me, and I can give it to anyone I want to. [7] If you worship me, it will all be yours." [8] Jesus answered, "It is written: 'Worship the Lord your God and serve him only.'" [9] The devil led him to Jerusalem and had him stand on the highest point of the temple. "If you are the Son of God," he said, "throw yourself down from here. [10] For it is written: " 'He will command his angels concerning you to guard you carefully; [11] they will lift you up in their hands, so that you will not strike your foot against a stone.'" [12] Jesus answered, "It is said: 'Do not put the Lord your God to the test.'" [13] When the devil had finished all this tempting, he left him until an opportune time.

So the way the challenges entered Matthew and Luke is that Matthew made them up.

---

So what did Matthew intended with his particular, elaborate version?

It depends on what and whom he intends for us to understand the "tester" and the "accuser" to be. Was he speaking of a talking serpent? A manlike heavenly being? Or just a man: the Jewish High Priest? I think the latter. That's because the authors of the NT see everything Platonically, as metaphor.

Was John the Big Dipper the reincarnation of Elijah?:

> [Mar 9:11-13 NASB95] [11] They asked Him, saying, "[Why is it] that the scribes say that Elijah must come first?" [12] And He said to them, "Elijah does first come and restore all things. And [yet] how is it written of the Son of Man that He will suffer many things and be treated with contempt? [13] "But I say to you that Elijah has indeed come, and they did to him whatever they wished, just as it is written of him."

> [Mat 23:33 AMP] [33] "You serpents, you spawn of vipers, how can you escape the penalty of hell?

Etc.

And if so, unlike those who see this as a vision, he is led by the High Priest to Jerusalem (probably under guard) from the desert to Jerusalem, and on up to the [pinnacle](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinnacle%20architecture&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi2vJ7TxZSDAxVIjYkEHawyCCcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pinnacle%20archi&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDoNCAAQgAQQigUQQxCxAzoICAAQgAQQsQM6CggAEIAEEIoFEENQ9jxY1WxgpowBaANwAHgAgAGmAYgB7wWSAQM5LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=w-Z9ZfbOCsiaptQPrOWguAI&bih=998&biw=2065) of the Temple, for a better view.

Now, from historic descriptions of the 2nd Temple, it did not feature a pinnacle. Here's a typical depiction:

[image: The Second Temple (artist's conception)]

And notice also that the highest point is the roof of the most Holy Place (which represented "heaven." So by bringing Jesus there, he was bringing him to the highest point of the divine realm. In this view, the feet of the High Priest stood above God. God was under his feet. This brings to mind, and thus "fulfills" other passages, such as this one:

> [Isa 14:13-16 AMP] [13] "But you said in your heart, 'I will ascend to heaven; I will raise my throne above the stars of God; I will sit on the mount of assembly In the remote parts of the north. **[14] 'I will ascend above the heights of the clouds;** I will make myself like the Most High.' [15] "But [in fact] you will be brought down to Sheol, To the remote recesses of the pit (the region of the dead). [16] "Those who see you will gaze at you, They will consider you, saying, **'Is this the man who made the earth tremble, Who shook kingdoms,**

But isn't that about "Satan"? No, that tradition is bogus. It was originally addressed to "the King of Babylon." But Matthew takes it as metaphor for the Highest Priest, Caiaphas, and Babylon as Jerusalem:

> [1Pe 5:13 NASB95] [13] She who is in Babylon, chosen together with you, sends you greetings, and [so does] my son, Mark.

John of Patmos also has the destruction of Jerusalem referred to as "Secret Babylon"

> [Rev 17:5-6 NKJV] [5](https://youtu.be/rS57A_2yWg4) And on her forehead a name [was] written: MYSTERY, BABYLON THE GREAT, THE MOTHER OF HARLOTS AND OF THE ABOMINATIONS OF THE EARTH. [6](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinnacle%20architecture&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi2vJ7TxZSDAxVIjYkEHawyCCcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pinnacle%20archi&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDoNCAAQgAQQigUQQxCxAzoICAAQgAQQsQM6CggAEIAEEIoFEENQ9jxY1WxgpowBaANwAHgAgAGmAYgB7wWSAQM5LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=w-Z9ZfbOCsiaptQPrOWguAI&bih=998&biw=2065) I saw the woman, **drunk with the blood of the saints and with the blood of the martyrs of Jesus.** And when I saw her, I marveled with great amazement.

> [Luk 13:33 NKJV] [33] "Nevertheless I must journey today, tomorrow, and the [day] following; for it cannot be that a prophet should perish outside of Jerusalem.

I've shown that this never happened, but read metaphorically, it does "fulfill" (in a whale of a tale) Isaiah 14 and so on. That is how it is intended to be read. Not as history, but as religious mythology.

---

But when Jesus and Caiaphas stood together on top of God's Holiest Place, Caiaphas' fate was sealed, ala the King of Babylon. We see similar tropes elsewhere:

> [Mat 11:23 NKJV] [23] "And you, Capernaum, who are exalted to heaven, will be brought down to Hades; for if the mighty works which were done in you had been done in Sodom, it would have remained until this day.

In contrast, though the Christ is "brought down to Hades," he would be raised to God's right hand.

---

> [Mat 4:8-11 NKJV] [8] Again, the devil took Him up on an exceedingly high mountain, and showed Him all the kingdoms of the world and their glory. [9] And he said to Him, "All these things I will give You if You will fall down and worship me." [10] Then Jesus said to him, "Away with you, Satan! For it is written, 'You shall worship the LORD your God, and Him only you shall serve.' " [11] Then the devil left Him, and behold, angels came and ministered to Him.

---

**ANSWER ALERT**

So what could they see in this metaphoric story? They saw Judea, the Promised Land. Not China, Australia or anything like that:

> [Mat 10:6 NKJV] [6](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinnacle%20architecture&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi2vJ7TxZSDAxVIjYkEHawyCCcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pinnacle%20archi&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDIHCAAQgAQQGDoNCAAQgAQQigUQQxCxAzoICAAQgAQQsQM6CggAEIAEEIoFEENQ9jxY1WxgpowBaANwAHgAgAGmAYgB7wWSAQM5LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=w-Z9ZfbOCsiaptQPrOWguAI&bih=998&biw=2065) "But go rather to the lost sheep of the house of Israel.

> [Mat 15:24 NKJV] [24] But He answered and said, **"I was not sent except to the lost sheep of the house of Israel."**

Caiaphas was offering Christ to be the King of Israel IF he would in turn be subject to the current ruler, the Highest Priest.

---

For those still reading... I want to explain some very important biblical ideas, briefly, that will make this clearer.

- Matthew has crafted his gospel to "fulfill" Ezekiel 37, which describes/predicts that the Messiah was to restore the United Kingdom of Israel, (not Britain)
- he wants to fulfill the land promises
- once these are fulfilled, physically and mystically, by Jesus, then 40 years later he has Jesus return and destroy all of physical Jerusalem and the Temple, establish "The Israel of God" as a mystical city aka New Jerusalem, City on a Hill, the Light of the World, the House of Prayer for All Nations, etc.:

> [Mat 5:14-16 NKJV] [14] "You are the light of the world. A city that is set on a hill cannot be hidden. [15] "Nor do they light a lamp and put it under a basket, but on a lampstand, and it gives light to all [who are] in the house. [16] "Let your light so shine before men, that they may see your good works and glorify your Father in heaven.